# Write into openai-whisper

Tags: openai-whisper

I wrote a python program for transcribing and writing the result to a file. Writing to a file via WITH. The problem is that the text of the first audio is recorded in the file - I change the link to the audio, start transcription, and the text of the previous audio is recorded. What to do??

1. Deleted the previous text file. 2. Changed the audio file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.